# Ubuntu - Python installations

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, matplotlib, installation

I have python-2.7.9 installed on my machine and I am trying to install numpy, matplotlib, pyopengl, and pyqt4.

I've installed pyqt4 using the source file and it imports fine when using python, however, i get an error for the remaining packages.... `no module named numpy`.

I installed numpy and matplotlib using the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install python-numpy 
sudo apt-get install pyhton-matplotlib`

I also tried using pip and aptitude but I still get the same error..im not sure what I am doing wrong or how to fix these issues. Does anyone have any advice?

**UPDATE:**

Using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

These are the errors I get:

`Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 5 2015, 11:24:57)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", or "license" for more information.`

import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: Mo module named numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ubuntu 14.04, the packages you want are not called simply `numpy` and `matplotlib`. Instead they are `python-numpy` and `python-matplotlib`. Thus to install them you need:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

EDIT:

Based on the comments below, the issue was a different version of python 2.7than the one provided by Ubuntu. More info in comments. An alias to the ubuntu's python seems to solved the problem.

Comment: i have both python-numpy and python-matplotlib but i still get the error

Comment: Just double check your question and procedure. It must be working. Probably you are doing something wrong, and the question is missing some information or what'a worse, it provides wrong information, like that you use the following command `sudo apt-get install numpy`.

Comment: yes I just updated my question. I've tried using sudo apt-get install python-numpy...i also tried pip install numpy. I still get the same error

Comment: Could be something with the path? when I do echo $PYTHONPATH it returns nothing..

Comment: Ubuntu comes with both python 2 and 3. Are you sure you installed it for the version you use?

Comment: Well I'm using python 2.7.9. I'm not sure what version is installed when you use python-numpy

Comment: I'm also wondering about your python version 2.7.9. According to [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python) it should be 2.7.5/6. I also work on ubuntu 14.04 and have 2.7.6. Did you install newest python yourself?

Comment: yes I believe I did sudo apt-get install python..is there a way to switch versions

Comment: If you run in the terminal `which python; python -V` what it says?

Comment: It says, /usr/local/bin/python  Python 2.7.9

Comment: So, i think this is the reason. For me it says `/usr/bin/python  Python 2.7.6`. Everthing you install sudo apt will go to different folder than yours, as its not standard package. Try to use direct path to ubuntu's python i.e. `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: I've added /usr/bin/python to my PATH and PYTHONPATH, but I still get the same error. is there a way to change my python version to 2.7.6?

Comment: You could try making alias `alias python=/usr/bin/python` in terminal.

Comment: Ah i see. thank you! this seems to have worked. However, if i exit the terminal will the alias still remain?

Comment: i just checked..it doesn't. i would have to create an alias every time?

Comment: You can add it to your .bashrc, i.e.: `echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python" >> ~/.bashrc`. When you start bash, it will have the alias defined automatically.

Comment: no worries. glad I could help. If so, accepting the answer would be appreciated.